# How to remove the "0," in a fraction in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace, split, double

I have a float value of a current weight like e.g. "79.3" kilograms.
I split the float value into a kilogram and a grams value.

I get the right amount of kilograms when parsing the float-value to int.
Then I get the fractional part of the float-value. This fractional part looks like "0,3" which means 0.3 kilograms or 300grams.
In my Programm I can only have 0,100,200,..,900 Grams which would stand for 0-9.
My goal is to remove the "0," so I only get the value of "3".

This is my code for now and I tried some decimal formatting too, but I didn't know how to do it:

```
public void setCurrentWeightInTheNumberPickers() {
    float currentWeightAsFloat = weight_dbHandler.getCurrentWeightFloat();
    int currentWeightKilograms = (int) currentWeightAsFloat;
    double fractionOfGrams = currentWeightAsFloat % 1;
    DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    String rounded = df1.format(fractionOfGrams);
    rounded.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");

} //public void setCurrentWeightInTheNumberPickers()
```

Comment: Just multiply ftaction with 10f...

Comment: What do you want if your decimal part is like `0.0030` I guess `30` right?

Comment: "*This fractional part looks like "0,3" which means 0.3 kilograms or 300grams. My goal is to remove the "0," so I only get the value of "3".*" is confusing. What that 3 would stand for? What if you have 0.03, what value would you expect? Also 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can simply do that. No need for strings.

```
float f = 3.3f;
int g = (int)f;
int h = Math.round((f - g)*10);
```

and since h is supposed to be grams, you might as well make it *1000

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the "*10" instead of "*1000"
Your answer was brief and it solved my problem.
Now when I enter 77.5kg in my mobile App, the app returnd 77 and 5 which is perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

Given a string

```
String gram = "0,3";
```

you can just do:

```
gram = gram.substring(gram.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
```

which gives the following output when printed

> 3

Answer (score 1):

I view this primarily as a math, not a Java, problem.  Given a float input in units of kilograms, to obtain only the kilogram component, we can take the floor.  To get the grams component, we can multiply by 1000 and then take the mod of 1000.

```
double input = 79.321;
double kg = Math.floor(input);
System.out.println("kilograms: " + kg);
double g = Math.floor((1000*input) % 1000);
System.out.println("grams: " + g);

kilograms: 79.0
grams: 321.0
```

Note: I am using `double` here instead of `float`, only because `Math.floor` returns `double` as its return value.